# I want to write a mobile app that interacts with the Instagram API, what language should I use/learn?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

Preferably Android and IOS, I have no mobile dev experience, just very limited web dev experience. Considering python, ruby, c#, open to ideas. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Xamarin:

https://www.xamarin.com/download-it?_bt=101035044668&_bk=xamarin&_bm=e&gclid=CjwKEAjw_uvHBRDUkumF0tLFp3cSJACAIHMYy6w4lueD8GMy08uYBH3Py5ABAKCCLzP4jTVg0gvbMxoCZmzw_wcB

this framework allow you to Build apps for Android,Ios and Windows Phone in C# it comes for windows as a Visual studio extension.

Comment: Thanks, that looks great.

Comment: If that help you can you please mark the answer as selected by clicking the tick, thanks.